# Display polygons from PostGis database to Geodjango

Tags: maps, polygon, postgis, display, geodjango

Hey i just want to ask if there is a method to display polygons/lines in my postgis database using geodjango.

I tried using L.geoJson but nothing worked

Answer (score 0):

You can display it on a Leaflet map, importing the queryset as a variable:

```
{% load geojson_tags %}

<div id="map" style="width:100%;height:700px;"></div>

<script>
var map = L.map('map').setView([x_coord,y_coord],18);

var v_name = {{qs_name|safe}};

var map_var = L.geoJson(v_name , {style:layer_style}).addTo(map);
</script>
```